# How to calculate pairwise correlation only in Matalb

Tags: matlab

In Matalb, `corrcoef(x,y)` returns a correlation matrix. How can I get the pairwise correlation only (i.e. one of the off-diagonal terms)? I need to apply corrcoef (or whatever function returns only pairwise element) inside a `cellfun`, i.e.

`R = cellfun(@(u,v) PairwiseCorr(u,v), num2cell(X, 2), num2cell(Y, 2))`

Comment: Did you try [`corr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/corr.html)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, that works... if you have Statistics Toolbox add-on...

Comment: Well, actually, it doesn't seem to work with `corr` either. Seems to be something in the way it acts on cells...

Comment: OK, got it : need to flip rows to columns, i.e. `corr(u',v')`. Thanks

Comment: I think they need to be column vectors. To enforce the shape, you can do `corr(u(:),v(:))`. Note that `'` is complex conjugate transpose. It's safer to use `.'` if you just want to flip rows to columns.

Comment: Please write a self-answer if you found a way to solve your problem.